# jaas config contents reading to defaults [Kerberos]

Tags: oracle, kerberos, jaas, mit-kerberos

I am trying to connect to Kerberized oracle server through a keytab in a spring boot application.
I have the keytab and krb5.conf under resources and the jaas conf string under application.yml like :

```
kerberos:
  jaasContent: "Client { \n  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required\n  useTicketCache=false\n  useKeyTab=true\n  keyTab=\"%s\"\n  doNotPrompt=true\n  principal=\"%s\";\n};"
```

The end result of substituting with keytab and principal looks like this:

```
Client { 
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useTicketCache=false
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\krb5.keytab"
  doNotPrompt=true
  principal="XXXXXX@DOMAIN.AD.COMPANY.COM";
};
```

I have verified that I can read the keytab contents from resources by printing file contents in logs (although it is encoded).

I am setting this jaas to:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", jaasConf.toString());
```

When I run the application, I get the following error:

```
Running sql : SELECT to_char(systimestamp, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh.mi.ss.ff4 AM') FROM DUAL
>>>KinitOptions cache name is C:\Users\n714804\krb5cc_N714804
>> Acquire default native Credentials
Java config name: C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\krb5.conf
Loaded from Java config
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17.
>>> Found no TGT's in LSA
Failed to read from oracle: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The service in process is not supported. Unable to obtain password from user

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The service in process is not supported. Unable to obtain password from user

    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:371)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:452)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:462)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:473)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:480)
    at com.jpmorgan.ct.GetOracleTime.getOracleTime(GetOracleTime.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.jpmorgan.moneta.boot.logging.RequestLoggingFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggingFilter.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.jpmorgan.moneta.boot.logging.PerfLoggingFilter.doFilter(PerfLoggingFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.jpmorgan.moneta.boot.logging.MDCFilter.doFilter(MDCFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.jpmorgan.moneta.boot.web.ExcludeFontVaryHeadersFilter.doFilterInternal(ExcludeFontVaryHeadersFilter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The service in process is not supported. Unable to obtain password from user

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The service in process is not supported. Unable to obtain password from user

    at oracle.net.ano.AuthenticationService.g(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ano.AuthenticationService.e(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ano.Ano.negotiation(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:345)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:897)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:760)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
```

But when I do a manual kinit and obtain a Credentials cache in in my C:\Users\xxxxx\krb5cc_xxxxx
the application works perfectly.

From what I understand the Krb5LoginModule required in jaas.conf will read the keytab and other properties to generate a cache/TGT with the keytab provided and I wouldn't have to do a kinit ?

I further debugged taking on to this understanding and found out that that jaas is not taken to effect and Krb5LoginModule called with some default settings.

```
Unable to obtain password from user at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:897)
```

Krb5LoginModule.java:897 led me ktab == null and useKeytab = false, which contradict to what I have set in the jaas.conf

I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand if there is something wrong in my jaas.conf or in the approachh I am taking.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked out the [JDBC developer's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/jjdbc/client-side-security.html#GUID-97E88D18-B590-4313-87B8-EE422DA644B3) for reference?